# Exceptions when creating a Apache Tiles simple application

Tags: java, tomcat, tiles

I'm trying to create my first Tiles web page.
I'm using [this tutorial](http://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/tutorial/) and after all configs are done I'm getting this exceptions:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(TilesAccess.java:124)
    at org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getContainer(TilesAccess.java:107)
    at org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess.getCurrentContainer(TilesAccess.java:174)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertDefinitionModel.execute(InsertDefinitionModel.java:95)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertDefinitionTag.doTag(InsertDefinitionTag.java:254)
    at org.apache.jsp.menu.menu_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertDefinition_005f0(menu_jsp.java:92)
    at org.apache.jsp.menu.menu_jsp._jspService(menu_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I created the tiles-defs.xml and added all configs to my web.xml.

Comment: doesn't look like your TilesInitializer (or initial configuration) is working…

Answer (score 0):

I walking same tutorial and found missing configuration. Add this to `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.simple.SimpleTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This listener will track app start and will configure tiles with default way (main tiles config should be only here: `/WEB-INF/tiles.xml`) as far as this is hardcoded in default configuration.